# VSCode Python Language Server not shown anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

VSCode Information:

```
Version: 1.41.1 (system setup)
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T14:58:56.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Python Extension Information:

```
Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Intellisense, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, snippets, and more.
Version: 2019.11.50794
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
```

VSCode doesn't show the notification window to use `Python Language Server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `settings.json` file to see if jedi is enabled ?